# actuator refresh uncommited local file changes

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-boot-actuator, spring-cloud-config

I am setting up a spring cloud server which try to get some properties from a git repo as follow :

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri = file:///${user.home}/PersoWorkspace/cloud-config
```

In my spring cloud client i try to get theses properties as follow :

```
spring.cloud.config.uri = http://localhost:9090
```

I want to get the changes from the cloud-config repo without doing a commit/push

I tried to add

```
spring.cloud.config.override-none= true/false
spring.cloud.config.allowOverride= true/false
spring.cloud.config.override-system-properties= true/false
```

But i always need to commit the changes to get them in my cloud client

How can i get the changes of my properties on the cloud-config without commit them ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using Spring Config poiting to a file system rather than a git repository ?

Comment: Thank you for your response, finally i used 

`spring.cloud.config.server.native.searchLocations`  instead of    

`spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri` and it works